# Cannot convert input as fraction string to float

Tags: python

Here is my program :

```
r = float(input())
for i in range (1,6):
    L = r-i
    k = L//2
    if isinstance(k, int):
        print(L, r-L)
    else :
        print("IDK !")
```

When i plug in `17/6` this is the error that i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '17/6'
```

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: None of the string to number conversion functions will evaluate a mathematical expression like addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division. They only convert a string containing a plain number to a Python number.

Comment: Fractions are not a native numeric type in Python (and wouldn't be type `float` even if they were). If you want that value to be calculated when provided as input like that, you'll need to actually parse out the parts of the fraction. You may want to go back to basics and check the documentation on the functions and operators you're using.

Comment: @SiHa That is not correct. Strings can be converted to a number using the float() operator, you can try it yourself. The problem isn't that it isn't possible. The problem is that OP is confused about how that function works.

Comment: @LTheriault I am well aware of that, thank you. The point I am making is that a fraction is not a floating-point number. It may well be able to be represented by one, but cannot be directly converted. I agree that my comment could be interpreted to mean that *any* string cannot be converted to a number. This is not what I meant. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: I had no way of knowing that's what you meant because you had also made a comment disagreeing with me when I was trying to explain that 17/6 the operation and17/6 the fraction representation were not equivalent in Python for the reasons you're giving now

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to reformat your code so that it's readable for other people. But to answer your question, it's because "17/6" comes in as a string value. Converting a string to a float will convert actual numbers into a float. Numbers in Python are represented as decimals, not fractions, so 17/6 is "17 divided by 6" and not "17 over six". You would need to find a way to parse that as an operation to produce a float instead of trying to convert it directly to a float.

EDIT: To clarify, I understand that the fraction 17/6 and the results of dividing 17/6 are mathematically equivalent. That does not mean that python treats them as equivalen representation because fractions are not a native data type. If you print 17/6, it's not showing you a representation of 17/6. It's printing the result of 17.**truediv**(6).

Comment: *"17 divided by 6"* **is** *"17 over six"*

Comment: I understand that they're equivalent mathematically. If the result of division and a fraction are the same thing in python, then they should both be float. However, as OP shows, you can't perform the same type of conversion because fractions are not a native data type to python.

Comment: Thanks ! for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what your trying to do but if you want Python to evaluate your input say 17/6 as if you where to have input the result of 17/6 as a float (2.833333333333333) replace

```
r = float(input())
```

with

```
r = float(eval(input()))
```

eval will evaluate the input string ("17/6") as 17.truediv(6) which is a float and then save that to r

also in my tests the line

```
if isinstance(k, int):
```

always evaluates to false as // doesn't change type to int and even if id did it would do so consistently